# Finding sum of the power series and the sum of the series

Tags: calculus

(1) Find the sum of the power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n$$

(2) Find the sum of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{3^n}$$

Any tips on solving the sum of series/power series?

Comment: See [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the second sum using the first with $x = 1/3$. As for the first, for $|x| <1$ write 
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n 
= x \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} 
= x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^n
= x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n
= x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x}
= \frac{x }{(1-x)^2}.
$$

Comment: How do you know about the x=1/3?  
edit: nevermind!

Comment: Since $|1/3| < 1$ you can make the substitution $x=1/3$ in the formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n$ found above

Comment: wait actually how do we get to 1/3 first?

Comment: So, from the above deduction you have 
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}
=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty n (1/3)^n
= \frac{1/3}{(1-1/3)^2}
$$
You just plug the value $x=1/3$ into the above formula! :)

Comment: I get that part but how do we know to use x=1/3?
Would it just be the first term?

Comment: Because the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}$ *is* the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n$ when $x=1/3$. That was the point of the *first* equality in my above comment.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to find the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3x^n$? It seems related, but I'm failing to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you take the power series $1/(1-x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and take the derivative term by term, what do you get? Also the second series is a special case of the first where $x = 1/3$.